# Importing Groups to WebApp QGIS2Web

Tags: qgis2web

I have a file with shapefiles organized into different groups, though once I export the file using QGIS2Web the web version has the list of all shapefiles ungrouped.

How can I keep the shapefiles grouped in the web version?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that qgis2web support for layer groups is simply very poor indeed. It's a long-standing weakness of the plugin:

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/175